# Keep getting the error "No Python at" for this login program i made on python

Tags: python

the file will not even run it just shows that "No Python at" then tells me the location of the file i don't know why.

for the code to run and allow me to store a username and password into a textfile and be able to recall that information to login
tis id the code

```
class MyLogin:
    def store_user(self, password='', user=''):
        file = open('users.txt', 'r+')
        file.write(password + '>>' + user + '\n')
        file.close()

    def login_user(self):
        file = open('users.txt', 'r+')
        array1, array2, array3 = [], [], {}  # initialize empty lists and dictionary
        lines = file.readlines()  # read all lines from the file
        for x in lines:
            fields = x.split(" >> ")
            array1.append(int(fields[0]))  # convert score to int and append to array1
            array2.append(fields[1].replace("\n", ""))  # remove newline and append name to array2
            array3[int(fields[0])] = array2[-1]  # create dictionary mapping scores to names

        current_usernames = set(array2)
        z = input('Enter you username')
        if z not in current_usernames:  # check if entered player name is valid
            print(f"Username '{z}' not found. Please login.")
            file.close()
            return

        user_password = set(array1)
        r = input('enter password')
        if r not in user_password:  # check if entered player name is valid
            print("password not found. Please retry.")
            file.close()
            return
        file.close()

MyLogin()
while True:
    print("_________________________________________________________________")
    question = input("B. To join 1\n"
                    "C. To Login 2\n"
                    )  # get the input from the user
    if question == "1":  # if 1, then
        MyLogin()  # display summary of scores, you should already have the manager.txt
    elif question == "2":  # if 2, then add new player
        word = int(input("Enter your Username: >> "))  # the score
        y = input("Enter your Password >> ")  # the player
        Login_user(y, word)  # add the player
    else:  # otherwise print out invalid and continue
        print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
    print("_________________________________________________________________")  # for niceness
    print("Scoreboard summary:")  # summary...
    MyLogin()
```

Comment: Can you include the full error message please?

Comment: could you post how are you running the program and the error you are getting?

Comment: It sounds like Python isn't installed where it needs to be installed in order to run it in the way that you are trying to run it. More details on your part would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MyLogin does nothing.You didn't even call that. You can try this. In your class z and r both do nothing while u giving these inputs. Also, u can't call your MyLogin().login_user by using only Login_user even their syntax is not match. I set up your code for applying it should be good.

First step is I initialized your class.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.file = open('users.txt', 'r+')
```

Second step is changed your store_user. In this part u can put username and password to sign up new user into your storage.

```
def signup_user(self,password,user):

    self.password = password
    self.user = user
    self.file.write(self.password + '>>' + self.password + '\n')
    self.file.close()
```

Third step is check login_user. You can put username and password to check.

```
def login_user(self,username,user_password):
    self.username = username #FOR Z
    self.user_pw = user_password #FOR R
    
    array1, array2, array3 = [], [], {}
    lines = self.file.readlines()
    for x in lines:
        fields = x.split(" >> ")
        array1.append(int(fields[0]))  
        array2.append(fields[1].replace("\n", "")) 
        array3[int(fields[0])] = array2[-1] 

    self.current_usernames = set(array2)
    # z = input('Enter you username') # Swtiched z with username
    if self.username not in self.current_usernames:  
        print(f"Username '{self.username}' not found. Please login.")
        self.file.close()
        return

    self.user_password = set(array1)
    # r = input('enter password') #switched R with password
    if self.user_pw not in self.user_password: 
        print("password not found. Please retry.")
        self.file.close()
        return
    self.file.close()
```

I haven't tested this but u can edit my code if there is any bug.

I'd like to suggest studying on fundamentals of OOP.

```
class MyLogin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('users.txt', 'r+')

    def signup_user(self, password, user):
        self.password = password
        self.user = user
        self.file.write(self.password + '>>' + self.password + '\n')
        self.file.close()

    def login_user(self,username,user_password):
        self.username = username #FOR Z
        self.user_pw = user_password #FOR R
        
        array1, array2, array3 = [], [], {}
        lines = self.file.readlines()
        for x in lines:
            fields = x.split(" >> ")
            array1.append(int(fields[0]))  
            array2.append(fields[1].replace("\n", "")) 
            array3[int(fields[0])] = array2[-1] 

        self.current_usernames = set(array2)
        # z = input('Enter you username') # Swtiched z with username
        if self.username not in self.current_usernames:  
            print(f"Username '{self.username}' not found. Please login.")
            self.file.close()
            return

        self.user_password = set(array1)
        # r = input('enter password') #switched R with password
        if self.user_pw not in self.user_password: 
            print("password not found. Please retry.")
            self.file.close()
            return
        self.file.close()
        
my_login = MyLogin()

while True:
    print("_________________________________________________________________")
    question = input("B. To join 1\n"
                    "C. To Login 2\n"
                    )  
    if question == "1":  
        name_input = int(input("Enter your Username: >> ")) 
        pw_input = input("Enter your Password >> ") 

        my_login.signup_user(name_input,pw_input)
    elif question == "2":  
        name_input = int(input("Enter your Username: >> ")) 
        pw_input = input("Enter your Password >> ") 
        my_login.login_user(user_password=pw_input, username=name_input)  # add the player
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
    print("_________________________________________________________________")
    print("Scoreboard summary:")
```

Comment: thanks, i am will take your advice to heart